# How to find input impedance for this op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, thevenin, single-supply-op-amp

[image]

The simulation gives an output voltage of 1.427V and Av of 10. Based on the equation Av= -R2/Ri, Ri should be 7kΩ. However, when I calculate the total impedance using R3+(R1//R4), the impedance is only 5.833kΩ.

What is the correct way to calculate the input impedance? Why can't I combine R3, R4 and R1 together as Ri to feed into Av equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combined input impedance is 5.833 kΩ so no problem there. What you are missing is that R3 and R4 also form a potential divider of 2:1. So your input voltage is reduced by 2 and becomes equivalent to 50% of the voltage sourced from an impedance of R3||R4.

[image]

This means that your "new input resistor" value is R3||R4 + R1 = 3.5 kΩ

Given that R2 is 10 kohm, your circuit gain is 50% of 10/3.5 = 1.42857 and, if you accurately reported what your simulation said (*1.427V*) you would get agreement with the above.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgXALr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By definition the input resistance is the resistance "seen by the source". As far as the Op-amp is in the linear region we know that the inverting input voltage and non-inverting input voltage are equal to zero. So R1 is parallel to R4 and it can be easily seen that the resistance the source faces is (R4||R1)+R3 = 5.83 k ohm.
To calculate the gain it is easy to calculate the value of voltage in the (in1) and then simplify the circuit a bit, like you see in the picture